# How to store multiple files on server java

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

im making a client server application in `java` using `sockets`
I've implemented the basic client and server, the client can send pictures to the server and the server stores them but i don't know how to store multiple files. At the moment im using the following code to store the file received from the client

```
while(true)
    {
        Socket connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        try (DataInputStream receivedFromClient = new DataInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
                FileOutputStream saveToServer = new FileOutputStream("files/file.jpg"))
        {    
            int i;
            while ((i = receivedFromClient.read()) > -1)
            {
                saveToServer.write(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how im saving one file, and the file gets overwritten by any new file that the server receives. I want to store multiple files that the client sends, how would i do that? Also how would i set the names of the files that get received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a file name argument to the method in which this code block exists that will allow you pass the filename. Or autoincrement the file name using a static counter, if that is appropriate.

The problem is you are using the same file name every time, as it is hardcoded here:

```
FileOutputStream saveToServer = new FileOutputStream("files/file.jpg"))
```

Instead, the string you are passing to FileOutputStream should be variable, ex.

```
FileOutputStream saveToServer = new FileOutputStream(yourStringVariable))
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm :) ... can't believe i didn't think of that :/ ... How would you suggest i change the file types.  From `.jpg` to `.txt` or any other type? I've implemented the `FileChooser` to accept txt, jpg, and gif

Comment: FileChooser? Do you mean javax.swing.JFileChooser? If so there is a good article here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#filters
In principle the file output stream will name it to whatever string you give it (ie any file extension, or none). So if you are using a UI then you could add filters to control the supported file types

Comment: Yes, i am talking about the JFileChooser... I meant on the server. How would i change the extension of the file in the given code.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The extension is part of the file name string. In the code above, just modify the string (ie. change files/file.jpg to files/file.txt).
In JFileChooser the selected file will include the extension, so you just have to pass the whole string (chooser.getSelectedFile().getName()). Is that what you are asking?